# Fair game of dice tossing

Tags: probability

The claim 1 is that if one player toss one 20-side dice and the other three 6-side dice and the game is won by having the largest sum, it is a fair game.

The claim 2 is that this will not be a fair game if this game is extended to any number of players larger than 2--fair meaning each one player have equal chance of winning.

This is supposed to be answered within seconds. I have no way to see it other than doing large amount of computation. What is the trick?

Comment: If there are more than $2$ players, which players get which dice?

Comment: what are the numbers of the 20 sided dice and what about ties?

Comment: @pepster there is no ambiguity there--game just needs to be fair

Comment: @quasi The implication is that so long as not all players get the same type of dicing, it is going to be unfair.

Comment: @quasi For example, the three player game will be unfair for: 2 players 6-side dice, 1 player 20-side dice; or for 1 players 6-side dice, 2 player 20-side dice;

Answer (score 1):

For the first claim, I would simply argue that both distributions are symmetric about the same mean (10.5), therefore for any pair of values where $p_1 > p_2$, there is an "equivalent" pair, reflected through the mean, such that $p'_1 < p'_2$, which is equally likely to be obtained.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an argument to show that the $2$-player game is fair . . .

Assume the $20$-sided die has face values $1,2,3,...,20$, with all values equally likely, and assume three standard $6$-sided dice.

Let $X$ be the score for player $1$ (the value of the $20$-sided die), and let $Y$ be the score for player $2$ (the sum of the values of the three $6$-sided dice).

Then player $1$ wins, ties, or loses, according as $X > Y$, $X=Y$, or $X < Y$.

Note that $1\le X\le 20$, and $3\le Y\le 18$.

For each pair of integers $(a,b)$ with $1\le a\le 10$, and $3\le b \le 10$, let $T[a,b]$ be the event
$$
\begin{cases}
X\in \{a,21-a\}\\[4pt]
Y\in \{b,21-b\}\\
\end{cases}
$$
Suppose event $T[a,b]$ happens.

Let $x\in\{a,21-a\}$, and let $y\in\{b,21-b\}$.

If player $1$ wins with $(X,Y)=(x,y)$, then player $1$ loses with $(X,Y)=(21-x,21-y)$.

If player $1$ ties with $(X,Y)=(x,y)$, then player $1$ ties with $(X,Y)=(21-x,21-y)$.

If player $1$ loses with $(X,Y)=(x,y)$, then player $1$ wins with $(X,Y)=(21-x,21-y)$.

By symmetry, the two cases

- $X=a$$\\[4pt]$

  $X=21-a$

are equally likely.

Similarly, the two cases

- $Y=b$$\\[4pt]$

  $Y=21-b$

are equally likely.

Thus, given that the event $T[a,b]$ happens, the two players have an equal chance of winning.

Since this is true for all such events $T[a,b]$, it follows that the game is fair.

Comment: This is good but is too complicated to be accepted (I mentioned "it must be solved within seconds"). See my answer. And welcome to attempt the multiplayer case.

Comment: @Daniel Li: The symmetry can be understood mentally. There is no need to write anything down.

Answer (score 0):

For 2, to win a multiplayer game you need to do well. The $20$ sided die has higher variance than $3d6$ so you want it.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out the 2 player case. The solution is simpler than what is presented here: for each number that can be achieved by 3-coin combo, say $x$, there is another number $y$ where $x+y=19$ such that $P(W>x)=P(W<y)$, $W$ is the r.v. representing 20-side coin toss.

Comment: This isn't quite right. For $x = 18$, you have $y=1$. Then $P(W > x) = 2/20$, while $P(W < y) = 0$.